# FindViewById return null from another Activity

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

- I'm trying to extend an activity that handle the toolbar initialization that will be in each activity of my project.
- In this `ToolbarActivity`, when I try to use `findViewById`, it return `null`.

I've look many subjects on this website but none of them seems to give me a correct answer :

**Here is my code :**

```
    public abstract class ToolBarActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    private DrawerLayout _drawerLayout;
    private ListView _mLeftDrawer;
    private SupportToolBar _mToolBar;
    private MyActionBarDrawerToggle _mDrawerToggle;
    private List<Tuple<string, int>> _items;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        int layout = GetLayoutResource();
        SetContentView(layout);
        InitToolBar(savedInstanceState);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Initialize the Toolbar and the leftDrawer
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="savedInstanceState"></param>
    private void InitToolBar(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        _mToolBar = FindViewById<SupportToolBar>(Resource.Id.toolBarMenu);
        _drawerLayout = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawerLayout1);
        _mLeftDrawer = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listviewleft);
        InitListView();
        SetSupportActionBar(_mToolBar);
        _mDrawerToggle = new MyActionBarDrawerToggle(this, _drawerLayout, Resource.String.openDrawer,
            Resource.String.Messages);
        _drawerLayout.AddDrawerListener(_mDrawerToggle);
        SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        SupportActionBar.SetHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        _mDrawerToggle.SyncState();
        CheckIfSavedInstance(savedInstanceState);
        _mLeftDrawer.ItemClick += leftDrawer_Clicked;
    }
```

**And here is my other activity that extends the previous one, I've rechecked the .axml, the id above are correct.**

```
public class MessagesActivity : ToolBarActivity
{

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MessageSystem);
    }

    protected override int GetLayoutResource()
    {
        return Resource.Layout.MessageSystem;
    }
}
```

Comment: I just needed to delete the SetContentView in MessagesActivity

Comment: Did you find a solution or not? if not let me know i will check this one out!

Comment: Yes thank you, I just needed to get rid of SetContentView in MessagesActivity

Comment: You want me to add that as an answer so you can mark it for others to find?

Comment: If it's possible for you, it would be great, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Setting a ContentView to the Activity was making it look for the Toolbar item in that contents XML and hence was always null.

Removing the `SetContentView` method solved the issue.